# WSO2 IS and JWT Token

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have security Usecase as below, was thinking to use WSO2 Identity Server -

An application needs to use authentication service from WSO2 Identity Server.  The application accepts user/password. Using these credentials, application needs to make an API call to WSO2 Identity Server, if the user is valid user, WSO2 Identity Server needs to reply back with valid JWT token and claims. (Users are mounted to one of the user stores in Identity Server.)

Can i use WSO2 Identity Server to support this Usecase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your description, Instead of redirecting the user to the authorization server, the client itself will ask the user for the resource owner's username and password. The client will then send these credentials to the authorization server along with the client’s own credentials (client id and client secret). Then the authorization server(WSO2 IS) will provide JWT token with requested claims. This is possible with WSO2 Identity Server.

please refer to: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant/

For setting up a sample : https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/deploying-the-sample-app/#deploying-playground2-webapp

For trying out the password grant using the sample  : https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/learn/try-password-grant/

Comment: thanks a  for this response , Is there a specific setup i need to do for generating JWTtoken and its format( header.payload.secret ) ?

Comment: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.9.0/develop/deploying-the-sample-app/#deploying-playground2-webapp in this documentation under deploying-playground2-webapp-> Configuring Service Provider you can select the token type. If you need a JWT select it as JWT. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/Configuring+Claims+for+a+Service+Provider Refer requested claims sections in this documentation for having user information in the token.

Comment: I was going through the link above , I can see the response is In following format

Comment: I was going through the link you mentioned above , I can see the sample response mentioned is In following format.      ‘ {"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":2510,"refresh_token":"5ba3dedc77581df5f84f9b228eef0b91","access_token":"ca19a540f544777860e44e75f605d927"}’.  This is not in JWT format like    header. payload.signature. Is there a configuration in WSO2 to get response in JWT format  ?

Comment: You should send scope=openid as a request parameter

Answer (score 0):

> An application needs to use authentication service from WSO2 Identity
>   Server. The application accepts username and password

You are using an application and users can authenticate to the application using username and password. The user exists in the userstore of Identity server. If the user exist in IS, IS can act as an identity provider and authenticate the user.

> if the user is valid user, WSO2 Identity Server needs to reply back
>   with valid JWT token and claims

There are different protocols WSO2 IS supports. If the service provider uses OpenID Connect, once the user is authenticated, an ID token(along with access token) will be sent to the service provider. This **ID token is a JWT token** which contains header.body.signature and the body contains the claims. In OpenID Connect, there are different grant types that can be used by the applications based on the requirements. **Authorization code, implicit and hybrid flow** can be used to authenticate the users and get user's claims as a JWT token along with access token.

WSO2 Identity Server supports all these grant types with OpenID Connect. When the user authenticates via the application, the WSO2 Identity Server will send the JWT token to the application.

Please refer to this [document](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/OpenID+Connect+Authentication) for further reference of OpenID Connect Authentication in WSO2 IS. Refer this [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) spec as well.

Comment: Thank a lot for the response . But my requirement is simple, we are evaluating to use WSO2IAM as unified user store , where we map user store from  coporate AD , and db store etc.  We will be introducing an application ,  this applicaion doesn't have capability to authenticate user from AD or Database. The idea is to pass user&password to WSO2IAM server , WSIAM server validate this user from AD user store and reply back JWT token and claims. Can WSO2IAM expose two api , one for access token and another one for refresh token. Where can i see simple documentation for WSO2 APIs for this usecase

Comment: Yes. This can be done with WSO2 identity server using OpenID Connect. Application does not need to authenticate the user. Identity server authenticate the user. Once the user is a valid user, the token endpoint of Identity Server will issue a JWT ID token along with access token and refresh token. You don't need two apis. Token endpoint will return all token in the token response.